# Grammar checking is not working for exclamatory sentences while using "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" in C# program

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, spell-checking

I am working on an application program to check the grammar mistakes of a text or markdown document. I have included the `"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word"` DLL in my `C#` program to check whether a sentence is grammatically correct or not.

It returns the result as false for CheckGrammar method, like if we have given

> `"myWord.CheckGrammar("who are you ?")"` 
>   the result we get is false, but this scenario is wrong.

How to overcome this?  What can I do to fix this issue?

Code sample:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application myWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

var fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(@"E:\test\Download.md");

foreach(var content in fileContent)
{
    bool isCorrect = myWord.CheckGrammar(content);
}
```

I need to check each sentence for grammar errors and show if how to fix them if any error is present.

Comment: The last time i looked it was 'grammar' ;-)

Comment: Is there a space between the final word and the exclamation/question mark?  If so then `false` would be the correct value